# How should I modify my code so that twosum function works?

Tags: python, python-3.x

The question is in Leetcode, which is:

> Given an array of integers nums and an integer target, return indices of the two numbers such that they add up to target. Each input would have exactly one solution, and you may not use the same element twice.

Here is my code for this exercise.

```
def twoSum(nums: List[int], target: int) -> List[int]:
    for i in range(len(nums)):
        for j in range(1,len(nums)):
            if nums[i]+nums[j]==target:
                return i,j
        return i,j
twoSum([8,3,7,9,2],9)
#Result: (0, 4)
```

The output is not correct as `8+2=10` (`nums[0] + nums[4]`) not equal to 9.

Why does this happen?

Comment: Why do you have `self` in the method definition if you don't have `class`?

Comment: I deleted the self argument, it works. Can you please tell me how to use class to solve this question ?

Comment: The indentation of `return []` IMHO is wrong. It makes the first `for` loop useless.

Comment: I could tell you *how*, but for you to understand, I would need to explain *why*. Teaching someone object orientation is more than 4 sentences in a stack overflow answer.

Comment: I changed my code, however, the output is still wrong answer. Why this happen ?

Comment: The second return makes no sense. The question states that a valid answer will always exist so remove it completely

Comment: A second issue is that you start the second loop at 1 even if `i` is bigger, which means you might return the same value twice, but never the first element of the list twice. You probably meant to start the second loop with `i+1`

Comment: @mousetail   If I remove the second return, there must be a alternative code so that the function can be valid. Can you please tell me  why my code can't return the right output?

Comment: No, you don't need a second return. The function will return None by default at the end if there is no solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two issues with your code:

- Your second `return` will just return at the end of the first iteration of the outer loop. Since i is still at 0 and j is all the way up to `len(nums) - 1`, you get (0, 4) as result. Removing it should resolve this issue.
- The innner loop starts with 1 instead of 0, but results like (1, 1) would still be possible. It is therefore necessary to adapt the inner loop based on the outer loops current state.

A possible solution would look like this:

```
def twoSum(nums: List[int], target: int) -> List[int]:
  for i in range(len(nums)):
    for j in range(i+1, len(nums)):
      if nums[i]+nums[j] == target:
        return i,j
  return -1, -1
```

The -1, -1 will only occur if there is no solution. Since it is stated in the question that there is always exactly one solution, this should never happen.

Comment: Thanks a lot!  Can you please tell me how to use class to solve this question?

Comment: In which way you would like the class to behave? The task you are trying to achieve is typical use-case for a function. Please elaborate on what the class should do. There are various solutions here.

Comment: Actually, this exercise is one of the question in LeetCode. There is class Solution: before def twoSum():,  so I can't udnerstand what's the meaning of that.